# Method pointer assigning

Tags: c++, methods

I use g++ and I am unable to compile the subsequent code despite writting it as described in http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible

I use also the switch -std=c++11

```
struct X{
    int a;
    int sz(){return 17;}
};

typedef int X::*methodPointer1();


methodPointer1 p1=X::&sz;
```

The error is:  "error: expected unqualified-id before ‘&’ token"

Any hint ?

Comment: Try `typedef int (X::*methodPointer1)();`

Comment: `despite writting it as described` - What do you mean by this? Was it in a book?

Comment: ALso it should be `&X::sz`

Comment: @JosephMansfield I added the reference in the question

Comment: @MattMcNabb when I change the "&" it gives: error: function ‘int X::* p1()’ is initialized like a variable

Comment: See this: http://ideone.com/nPl82S

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As noted by 0x499602D2 and Brandon, there are two separate problems in your code.

Proper syntax for `typedef`ing a pointer to member includes parentheses (just like with a pointer to function):

```
typedef int (X::*methodPointer1)();
```

To point your pointer to the proper member, use this syntax:

```
methodPointer1 p1=&X::sz;
```

The pointer-to-member syntax here is quite intuitive (`X::sz` is the name of the member function, so `&X::sz` is its address).

Comment: Why the document: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible Uses the other syntax with p1=X::&sz; ( and that doesn't work ). Why you use the syntax X::*methodPointer1 instead of *X::methodPointer1 (as in the line bellow where you use & ).

Answer (score 1):

A cleaner way to achieve what I think you're trying to achieve would be this:

```
#include <functional>

struct X {
    int a;
    int sz() { return 17; }
};

using methodPointer1 = std::function<int ()>;

X obj;
methodPointer1 func = std::bind(&X::sz, &obj);
func();
```

You can also have member functions which take arguments using `placeholders`:

```
struct X {
    int a;
    void set_a(int v) { a = v; }
};

X obj;
std::function<void (int)> func = std::bind(&X::set_a, &obj, std::placeholders::_1);
func(10);
```